# Internet Explorer waiting for localhost forever

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost

When I try to open localhost in IE9 or IE10 on Windows7 (64bit) with Apache 2.2 it takes forever to resolve the URL. Other browsers have no problem and immediately resolve the URL, only IE shows the "Waiting for localhost" in browser tab while loading icon keeps animating forever. Sometimes stopping and refreshing works, but often not. Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost doesn't make any difference, nor does resetting all IE settings. In my hosts file I have:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1 localhost
#   ::1 localhost
```

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found solution here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116971,119284

Following settings in httpd.conf worked for me.

Add these lines:

```
#Fix IE crashing Apache
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

above this line:

```
Include "d:/wamp/alias/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be caused by conflicts with `IIS`, if you have IIS installed

You can reset IE settings.. for more visit http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings-in-Internet-Explorer-9

This [tech](http://www.mytechguide.org/9560/reset-internet-explorer-ries/) guide describes the steps for resetting the advanced settings on Windows 7 for IE9.

Comment: No, IIS is not installed and resetting the settings didn't make any difference either.

Answer (score 0):

Just "Reset all zones to default level" in Internet Options > Security. Then restart IE

Comment: This button is disabled (grayed out) in my Win7 IE10.